# Not able to scroll down in DataGrid - WPF

Tags: wpf

I have written the following code :

```
<StackPanel Height="Auto">
   <Expander x:Name="Instrument_DataGrid" Header="Server Response" IsExpanded="True" Background="#FF0169FF" Foreground="White">
      <DataGrid x:Name="Inst_Process" ItemsSource="{Binding DataTable.DefaultView}"  AutoGenerateColumns="True" AlternatingRowBackground="Orange" CanUserReorderColumns="False" CanUserDeleteRows="False" CanUserAddRows="False" IsReadOnly="True" Height="Auto" Width="Auto" ColumnWidth="*" GridLinesVisibility="All" CanUserSortColumns="False">
             <DataGrid.Columns>
                      <DataGridTextColumn Header="Date Time" Binding="{Binding Date_Time}" Width="Auto"/>
                      <DataGridTextColumn Header="Server Name" Binding="{Binding Server}" Width="Auto"/>
                      <DataGridTextColumn Header="Message" Binding="{Binding Message}" Width="*" />
             </DataGrid.Columns>
      </DataGrid>
   </Expander>
</StackPanel>
```

And the output result of the above WPF design is as below :

[image: Output]

The problem is that when it runs and add rows in the datagrid I am not able to scroll the datagrid down to view more rows.

Can someone please help me in fixing the issue ? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Simply change the  Height="Auto" to Height ="400" if this is not you are looking for then keep it as Height="Auto" and Replace your stack panel with Grid.

Comment: If I change stack panel with grid then the background becomes blue and when rows gets added then datagrid expands.